# Is there a program where I can embed other programs' windows?

Tags: software-recommendation, tiling

I'm a developer and am often working on multiple different projects. It would help me a lot to have a software where I can create a profile for each project. If I start a profile it should open other programs I configured before and display them inside a single window. It should be possible to arrange them in tabs or also on a screen, one on the left and one on the right or similar.

I think mainly about browsers, PDF-viewers and terminals. This will give me access to the bug-tracker in a browser, log output in a console, specifications in a PDF and so on. It would make switching between projects much easier.

Is there anything or does anyone have a hint how it could be implemented with a scripting language?

Answer (score 3):

*What I'm offering is little more than a theory. It may lead nowhere.*

There are alternative window-managers like [`bluetile`](http://www.bluetile.org/), [`xmonad`](http://xmonad.org/) and [`awesome`](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) that can nest multiple windows in a nice tiling configuration (that is, all child windows are placed next to each other, rather than being allowed to overlap.

They can all (and there are a lot more than just those) be scripted in various languages. `bluetile` and `xmonad` both use Haskell while `awesome` uses lua.

The problem is, they replace the standard window manager. `bluetile` is the only one designed to work alongside traditional Gnome components so you might have most initial luck with that. Either way, you might battle to keep both a traditional desktop and be able to swap out for a tiled one. You might find that creating a new user for each project where each has its own desktop configuration, is what works best.

That said, you might find you prefer a tiled desktop for everything.

Comment: this looks promising, I'll have to evaluate a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

KDE provides exactly this functionality with a feature called 'activites'. This blog post gives a good overview of the concept:

http://hanschen.org/2011/02/04/activities-a-change-in-workflow/